# C# foreach loop take values from outer loop to inner loop

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

I have the below code.

```
int[] a = new int[] { 8, 9 };
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
     print i;
     int z;
     //during first iteration 
     z=8;
     during second iteration
     z=9;
}
```

Output should be something like this.
during first iteration i=0 and z=8
during second iteration i=1 and z=9

array a contains 2 elements. N and number of elements in array a will be always same. next my for loop will execute. during first iteration want z value should be 8(first element of array ) and second  iteration my z value should be 9. I want to map 1st element of integer array to first iteration of for loop and so on.

Comment: What is n? How big can it be? What is int[] a good for?

Comment: N is 2 in the above example. number of elements in the array and size of n is always same.

Comment: Check [this](http://ideone.com/jGSaR9)

Comment: This works out. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++) // or i < n if you want
{
    print i;
    int z = a[i]; // this line will get value from a one by one, 0, 1, 2, 3 and so on...
}
```

### Edit 1 -

After seeing the comments on the other answer, the array 'a' turns out is a dynamic array which have size `n` (which is 2)

the revised edition:

```
int n = 2;
int[] a = new int[n];
string input = null;

for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++) // or i < n if you want
{
    print i;
    input = Console.ReadLine();
    try {
        a[i] = int.Parse(input);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format(
            "You have inputted {0} for the {1} element",
            input, i
        ));
    } catch { Console.WriteLine("Non integer input"); i -= 1; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

int [] a = {8,9};

```
    for(int i=0; i< a.Length; i++)
    {
        int z = a[i]; //for taking value from array at the specific ith position
        Console.WriteLine("i: " + i + " z:" + z);
    }
```

Comment: This is not i am looking for

Comment: I just array a values hardcoded but i want it ynamically. I want to map first element of aray to the first iteration inside loop, second element of array to second iteration of for loop and so on

Comment: you want to input those values inside a for loop?

Comment: Yes i will use those for some calculations inside the loop

Comment: for that you should use List container that adds values dynamically

Comment: Yes something like that. How can i use list here

Comment: `List<int> a = new List<int>();
            int n = 2; // you can change it according to your need

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                string str = Console.ReadLine(); // make sure you enter an integer and conver it
                int z = int.Parse(str);

                a.Add(z);
            }

            foreach (int k in a)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(k);
            }`

Comment: kindly see my new answer

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    List<int> a = new List<int>();

    int n = 2; // you can change it according to your need



  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                string str = Console.ReadLine(); // make sure you enter an integer and conver it
                int z = int.Parse(str);

                a.Add(z);
            }

            foreach (int k in a)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(k);
            }
```